# A question about Riseup's OpenPGP guide on the sks keyserver pool

Tags: gnupg, openpgp, keyserver

While trying to follow [Riseup's guide to using the sks keyserver pool](https://riseup.net/en/security/message-security/openpgp/best-practices#use-the-sks-keyserver-pool-instead-of-one-specific-server-with-secure-connections), I was told to run commands in `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`; originally, I didn't have a `gpg.conf` file in `~/.gnupg`, so I ran `touch home/maen/.gnupg/gpg.conf` to create one.

The guide tells me to "use the following parameters in `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`", but when I run `cd /.gnupg/gpg.conf`, the terminal returns `bash: cd: .gnupg/gpg.conf: Not a directory`. Am I following the guide wrong? How do I fix it?

Edot: Also, when I run `gpg --list-keys` (or other `gpg` commands), `gpg: /home/[name]/.gnupg/gpg.conf:1: invalid option` and `gpg: /home/[name]/.gnupg/gpg.conf:2: keyword too long` repeat 462 times.

Comment: You can't `cd` to a file. You can `cd` to `~/.gnupg`, but you don't need to do that to edit `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`.

Comment: @muru how do I run `keyserver hkps://hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net` and `keyserver-options ca-cert-file=/path/to/CA/sks-keyservers.netCA.pem` inside `gpg.conf` then?

Comment: You don't need to "run" it. Edit it and put those lines inside it.

Comment: Right. How do I edit `.conf` files?

Comment: `gedit ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`, `nano ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`, `vi ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` - take your pick

Comment: Alright -- I opened the file up, but it's nonsense/undecipherable. A lot of it is "^@^@^@^@^@^@" repeated and numbers.

Comment: @muru forgot to @ you, sorry.

Comment: Also, when I run `gpg --list-keys` (or other `gpg` commands), `gpg: /home/[name]/.gnupg/gpg.conf:1: invalid option` and `gpg: /home/[name]/.gnupg/gpg.conf:2: keyword too long` repeat 462 times.